# Is there a way to create a windows shortcut to a pdf bookmark in Foxit reader?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, bookmarks, foxit-reader

I'm hoping to  create a windows shortcut (`.lnk`) that goes directly to a PDF bookmark. I'm using [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) & Windows 10.

I noticed someone from [eTutorials bodged up a hacky add-in](http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/pdf+hacks/Chapter+2.+Managing+a+Collection/Hack+18+Turn+PDF+Bookmarks+into+Windows+Shortcuts/) to do this using Adobe Reader, however this, frankly, is not enough to make me want to make the switch.

Is there a way to do this without abandoning ship to Adobe?

Edit (2021/05/05): is this a feature you'd like to see on Foxit reader? You can submit a feature request [on their website](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/login.html?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foxitsoftware.com%2Fsupport%2Fticket.html%3Futm_source%3Dclient-app%26utm_medium%3Dbutton%26utm_campaign%3Dreader10.1.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Foxit Reader manual](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/support/usermanuals.html)
does not list an argument for "go to bookmark X".

The only argument that pertains to bookmarks is:

```
pagemode=bookmarks        Open the bookmark panel in the Navigation Pane
```

I don't know if this lack justifies moving to the bloated Adobe Reader, or if the
solution you found will be that easy to use.

There are other free PDF viewers you could examine: SumatraPDF, Okular,
PDF-XChange Editor, Nitro Reader.